# How to prevent user to click on the back button after logout in asp.net mvc with cache enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser

I am trying to prevent user to click on the back button in all browsers after logout in ASP.NET MVC. This is a known problem, but all solutions which I've found propose me to disable cache by set 'Cache-Control' on 'no-cache'. I don't want to disable cache because my system is relatively huge and it needs this cache.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you can't prevent a user from using the back button, nor should you. You can *try*, but there's ways around it, and the browser may allow it regardless, based on user preferences. Regardless, it's an excellent way to piss off your users.

There's two aspects of this that need to be discussed. First, there's browser-specific "caching". I use quotes here, because I'm not talking about the traditional browser caching of resources. As an example, Chrome will often keep the previous rendered page in memory, so going "back" isn't technically issuing a request: it's just loading up the previously rendered page. That you won't be able to anything about. If the issue is that the user might be able to submit a form on the previous page, or similar, that can be solved via antiforgery tokens.

Second, there's the issue of server-side caching of user-specific information. If you're using `OutputCache` on authenticated pages, you should also be using `VaryByCustom` and returning some identifying information about the user (id, for example) as part of the custom string. Then, when the user logs out, they won't be able to get the cached copy, because it will no longer "belong" to them. This is actually more important, though, to prevent authenticated pages from being shared between multiple *logged in* users. If you're caching authenticated pages and not varying by the user, then you're potentially serving up private information to the wrong users.

Long and short, the solution is not to block the back button, which is not foolproof anyways. The solution is to design your application properly, such that it doesn't matter if the user goes back.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but I use this JQuery to catch the back button and resume a paginated state from the previous view. You could possibly use it to validate authorization and redirect.

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, '');

    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
        window.location.replace("/" + returnURL);
    });
}
```